# Problema pra baixar as dependencias do Maven no Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Sou noob no Maven e acabei pegando um projeto que estou com problema pra rodar no netbeans:

```
> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of
> its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not
> transfer artifact
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to
> central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer
> file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
```

Algum destemido poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi inserindo o código abaixo no meu pom.xml

```
  <repositories>
     <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository> 
     </repositories>
```